# Kendo Angular 2 Grid selection after grouping within a group

Tags: typescript, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I am building a **[Kendo Grid with Aggregate Group](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/grouping/grouping/)**
Is there any way so that we can select one/all rows within group and take action on it (like delete/delete all).

I tried below code but it is not complete. Below code gives me only grouped items only per page.
Is there any way to get all items from all pages which are grouped.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [group]="groups">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
            <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate let-group let-field="field" let-value="value">

               <strong>{{field}}</strong>: {{value}}
               <button (click)="click(group)">Delete</button>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
`})

private click(a:any){  console.log(a); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution. 
change the data binding using kendoGridBinding as per below below code

```
 `<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="grdData" [group]="groups" (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)"></kendo-grid>`
```

Then in component class

```
private click(a:any){ 
  let mockGrdState = this.State;
  mockGrdState.take = this.grdData.length;
  let processedData = process(this.grdData,mockGrdState);
  let grpData =  processedData.data.find(x => x.value == a.value);
  //write the code to delete data from grpData array  
}
public onStateChange(state: State) {
this.State = state;
}
```